# Compute the splitting field of $X^4 + 5 X^3 + 10 X^2 + 10 X + 5$ over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

> I'm trying compute the splitting field of $P(X) := X^4 + 5 X^3 + 10 X^2 + 10 X + 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This is what I thought: I tried find the roots of $P$ observing that

$$P(X-1) = X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 11$$

but I'm stuck here.

Can anyone give me a direction in order to find the splitting field of $P(X)$?

Comment: You made a mistake in $P(X-1)$.  *Hint*: $XP(X)=(1+X)^5-1$

Comment: $P(x)=\frac{(x+1)^5-1}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding roots of this polynomial is difficult so we use the following result:

> Result: Let $f (x) \in  F[x]$ and let $a \in F$. Then $f(x)$ and $f(x+ a)$ have the
>   same splitting field over $F$.

Here $-1 \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $f(x+(-1))=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ not $11$ in the constant term

But the last polynomial is a **Cyclotomic polynomial**.  So comparing to original polynomial, this one is easy to find!

Comment: Thanks! I thought that $f(x-1)$ would be a cyclotomic polynomial, but I was not identifying my mistake.